# postcss-preset-env: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tailwind-css

[image]

Any suggestion how to resolve this warning? I checked the whole project no where i used anything like

`justify-conten: end` or `align-items: end` and etc.

Still not sure why this warning showing everytime.

Using the following versions in `Angular 13`

```
"postcss": "^8.3.11",
"tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

**It turns out it was the issue the package I am using. It was not in my code.**

Comment: Without your CSS files, we won't be able to help much. I'd suggest simply searching `end` (or, if you have regex searching available in your editor, `:\s*end`). The log says the issue should be in `./src/styles.scss`.

Comment: @kenpachi, please can you further explain how the issue was the fault of the package you were using? I am having similar issues now.

Comment: Try using "flex-end" instead of "end". It worked for me.

Comment: I know this question is nearly 2 years old but could you please share which package issued this warning?

Comment: @DavisJahn I was using 'syncfusion' package that time. that specific version had this warning but later syncfusion team fixed it

Answer (score 165):

If you're using (S)CSS or SASS, you have to write `flex-start` or `flex-end` instead of `start` or `end` respectively.

Like this:

```css
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
```

Similar issue on github for mozilla: https://github.com/mozilla/addons-frontend/issues/7312

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unless "justify-content: end" was used in a grid, not in a flex layout. For me, autoprefixer emits this warning with grid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using

```
justify-content: start;
```

property instead of

```
justify-content: flex-start;
```

Using **'flex-start'** value solved it!

Answer (score -7):

(257:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

Comment: Please make more obvious which additional insight this provides, compared to the older 
 and upvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584054/7733418

Comment: This reads more like a bare bones copy paste of an error message than anything which might be considered an attempt to provide a solution. Please delete this or [edit] it according to [answer].